# php syntax highlighting in blade files

Tags: php, phpstorm, laravel-blade

I just started using PHPStorm (how did I live without Intellisense?) and it's pretty great. One issue I'm having is with syntax highlighting inside blade files. I start my views off with some php docblocks. Not sure where this practice started, but I think this was some carryover from my CodeIgniter days. so they start

```
<?php
/**
 * explanation of the file
 *
 * @author John Doe
 * @copyright 2015
 */
?>
```

the problem this causes is it prevents syntax highlighting of php code below. I believe I've isolated the problem to the `@` symbols, probably something to do with the Blade syntax highlighter, because if i remove the `@`s it works fine. is there a way in PHPStorm config to fix this? or do I need a different way to document my views?

Thanks!

Comment: Comment syntax in Blade is `{{-- --}}`. While you can use docblocks, as you've noticed they don't work too well.

Comment: @Andrew Brown AndI dont have any problem like you get there with phpstorm 8. Have you revert to default config and restart ?

Comment: this was a fresh install today. it only happens with files with the `.blade.php` extension, and if I use an `@` symbol

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm 8 has blade support. make sure you update to the latest version to get it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/

From official site:

Twig, Blade & Smarty Templates

Use the Twig, Blade or Smarty template engine to take advantage of productivity features when working with template files: configurable syntax highlighting for different constructs; syntax errors highlighting; functions and attributes completion; automatic insertion of paired braces, quotes and closing tags; and more.

Comment: yes, i'm already using that, but apparently the blade syntax highlighter is unable to distinguish docblocks. this might be a bug.